# Is there a simple example to use COM IFileBasedLogInit or ILog interfaces

Tags: c++, com

How do you use COM interfaces IFileBasedLogInit and ILog. I cannot seem to find any c++ code examples on the internet on how to use COM interface IFileBasedLogInit or ILog. This is what I've tried.

Also, Is this the right path to creating these interfaces
include txtlogpub.h -> use COM -> CoCreate -> ILog
include txtlogpub.h -> use COM -> CoCreate -> IFileBasedLogInit

I've tried this code below with success when creating the interfaces but when I try to use the interfaces I get errors.

```
    
    IFileBasedLogInit*  ifc_loginit = NULL;
    ILog*               ifc_logfile = NULL; 


    // Create the LogFile Instance.
    hr = CoCreateInstance(
        CLSID_SimpleFileBasedLog,
        NULL,
        CLSCTX_ALL,
        IID_ILog,
        reinterpret_cast<void**>(&ifc_logfile));
    
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        DISPLAY_MINOR_ERROR(L"We did it");
    
        //What file is this ILog interface pointing to????
        //What is a Blob???
        //ifc_logfile->AppendRecord...

        //SafeRelease(&ifc_logfile);
    }

    // Create the LogFile Instance.
    hr = CoCreateInstance(
        CLSID_SimpleFileBasedLog,
        NULL,
        CLSCTX_ALL,
        IID_IFileBasedLogInit,
        reinterpret_cast<void**>(&ifc_loginit));

        ULONG cbCapcityHint = 30000; // use of this variable is Shrouded in mystery

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        DISPLAY_MINOR_ERROR(L"We did it again!");

        hr = ifc_loginit->InitNew(L"logfile.txt", (ULONG)cbCapcityHint);

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            DISPLAY_MINOR_ERROR(L"success creating the log file");
        }
        else
        {
            DISPLAY_MINOR_ERROR(L"failed creating the log file");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just regular COM, you can read the documentation on [File-based Implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/txlogpub/nn-txlogpub-ilog#ilog-file-based-implementation), it explains how it works.
Here is some sample code:

```
int main()
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    {
        LSN lsn = {};
        
        // write
        ILog* log = NULL;
        if (SUCCEEDED(CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SimpleFileBasedLog, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_PPV_ARGS(&log))))
        {
            IFileBasedLogInit* init = NULL;
            if (SUCCEEDED(log->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&init))))
            {
                if (SUCCEEDED(init->InitNew(L"c:\\temp\\test.txlog", 0)))
                {
                    BLOB blob = {};
                    if (SUCCEEDED(log->AppendRecord(&blob, 1, TRUE, &lsn)))
                    {
                        wprintf(L"write success\n");
                    }
                }
                init->Release();
            }
        }
        log->Release();

        // open 
        if (SUCCEEDED(CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SimpleFileBasedLog, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_PPV_ARGS(&log))))
        {
            IPersistFile* file = NULL;
            if (SUCCEEDED(log->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&file))))
            {
                if (SUCCEEDED(file->Load(L"c:\\temp\\test.txlog", 0)))
                {
                    BYTE* bytes;
                    ULONG size;
                    if (SUCCEEDED(log->ReadRecord(lsn, NULL, NULL, &bytes, &size)))
                    {
                        wprintf(L"read success\n");
                    }
                }
                file->Release();
            }
        }
    }
    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This was a good example. I understand how to use this COM interface much better now.

Comment: I'm at the point now where I try to save the log but  I am running into an failure when I try to use the IPersistFile interface to save or get the current file name.

Comment: IPersistFile::GetCurFile(...) returns 0x80004001 E_NOTIMPL error. How do you implement or enable other functionalities to this interface?

Comment: It just means the IPersistFile implemented by the object behind CLSID_SimpleFileBasedLog doesn't implement GetCurFile or Save. To save the object, you can only use ILog methods (AppendRecord).